# Strange Xcode library C++ explicit setting

Tags: c++, ios, xcode

I am using Xcode 7.3.1 on el Capitan
I have included all *.a libraries to be included in the setting of 
Build Phases->Link Binary with Libraries. These would include:

```
libev.a
libhiredis.a
```

When I build, I notice under the link process:

```
Ld /Users/quantlabsnet/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

It adds the following flags of:

```
-lev -lhiredis
```

How are these flags generated as I have not included any additional flags under Linking option of:

```
Other librarian flags
Other linkers
```

As said, these 2 options are left blank. How do I suppress the automatically added switches of?

```
 -lev -lhiredis
```

Or how do I not get these generated in the link command. As it stands, the build complains of:

```
ld: library not found for -lev
```

Thanks

Comment: Im confused.  You added two libraries to be linked in the Build Phase settings, and you wondering why the linker is trying to link to them?  The flags -lev and -lhiredis are telling the linker to bring in those .a files (specifically they must be named libev.a and libhiredis.a), which you specifically added to the link list.

Comment: I understand that but somewhere within Xcode, there must a setting where it is forcing the libraries flags which are AUTOMATICALLY added:  -lev -lhiredis I am NOT adding this MANUALLY anywhere from within Xcode.

Comment: How else can the linker know that you want to include those libraries?  Xcode is simply generating link commands using the inputs you give it.  You told Xcode to link a few libraries, and so it passes that on to the linker.  What behavior do you expect instead?

Comment: I would not be posting this question if I knew that exact answer so maybe someones else can help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix,  ppecify the library in the Build Phases-Link binary with library. You also need to specify the library search path under Build Settings as well.